# Where to place a button that allows users to jump between process steps?

Tags: buttons

Consider I am on Page 5 of a website (which is the page before confirmation) and I have a button to come back to Page 1.
[image]

On Page 1 (below) I would have 5 buttons

- 3 buttons ("Previous", "Drop Down" and "Next buttons")
- 2 buttons ("Save button" & "Go back to Page 5 button")

[image]

Where should I place the "Go back to Page 5 button" button for the best experience?

Comment: UX experience is redundant. UX is User Experience

Comment: You have a button proliferation problem. This is where an interactive progress indicator comes in handy. [I just referenced this in another answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/108590/21857). Essentially, the user could navigate to step 5 (or any other valid step) by clicking in the progress bar.

Comment: At the point of need, that's where all the good call-to-actions should be found...

Answer (score 5):

**Design Principle #1 - KISS (Keep it Simple, Stupid)**

Your form experience is arguably suffering from over-design, the main evidence of which is the mess of buttons at the bottom of your second wireframe.

There are some very common/conventional design patterns you should utilize here to keep things simple for your users and you as a developer.

**Minimize the use of buttons**

Have one button to move forward, one button to move back, and (if you want) another button (or maybe a less prominent text link) to cancel/quit. The "Back" button is not present on the first step, the "Continue" button becomes a "Confirm" button on the last step.

**Show Progress**

Use a simple step indicator, with named steps, to show progress and to help with orientation within the process.

**Start Minimal and Build From There**

Unless you've researched/tested and found that it is critical to let the user jump around between steps (complicated design and development), then **focus first on providing a simple usable experience**, then later, if analysis shows that functionality is lacking, add on more features.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZPHav.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Can you please suggest where to place the Back to Confirmation button which would have user friendly impact. Either i can place the Back to Confirmation button below the Next button or below the Progress Bar. Placing it below the Progress Bar would be more user friendly as the user would be able to go back without being scrolling at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it's going to make much difference. You're asking out of some concern for user friendliness, but your mockups seem to show a variety of buttons, that change location from screen to screen. Your primary concern should be on working in some consistency to make it easier for users to build a mental modal. Rather than spending energy on worrying about the location of yet another button in an already potentially confusing UI, your time would be better spend at this stage on doing some basic user testing.

Comment: Just make a decision about where to put the "Back to Confirmation" button, and then test your UI with some representative users by having them carry out some of the essential tasks. You can do this at any stage e.g. with paper prototyping, or clickable mockups using Invision, or on an actual working prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this option either horizontal or vertical pattern. The user can jump to any step just by clicking on the number or details provided below.

**Horizontal**

[image]

**Vertical**

[image]

For reference: https://material.io/guidelines/components/steppers.html#steppers-types-of-steps

http://ui-patterns.com/users/6147/collections/steppers/screenshots

The user gets a clear picture of what steps are filled and needs to be filled.